# Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates PHP cURL

Tags: php, веб-программирование, xml, curl, https

При помощи cURL пытаюсь отправить xml запрос на определенный сервер партнерской компании, находящийся на защищенном сервере, но с ненадежной защитой (красная строка браузера).

Использую код

```
$curl = curl_init();

$xml = file_get_contents("php://input");

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => '8072',
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.ru:8072/xmlinterface.xml",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/xml",
    "Authorization: Basic AAAAAAAA" 
  ),
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Несмотря на то, что в коде прописано CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE (остановка cURL от проверки сертификата узла сети), выходит ошибка

> Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Подскажите, как исправить проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте еще дополнительно

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
```

Comment: спасибо. Ошибка была и в моем коде. Сейчас всё поправила и в вопросе